# Unable to define an associated functions named "new" that don’t have self as their first parameter

Tags: rust

I'm getting the following error during `cargo build`. And I'm not sure how to resolve this.

```
error: not &self method
  --> src/new_service.rs:20:18
   |
20 |     pub async fn new() -> Self {
   |                  ^^^
```

relevant part of src/new_service.rs:

```
pub struct Service {
    start: Event,
    collections: Vec<Collection>,
    clients: Vec<Client>,
}

#[dbus_interface(name ="org.freedesktop.Secret.Service")]
impl Service {
    pub async fn new() -> Self {
        Service {
            start: event_listener::Event::new(),
            collections: Vec::new(),
            clients: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
.....
```

Comment: What constraints does this `dbus_interface` impose? What crate is that from?

Comment: ah sorry: https://crates.io/crates/zbus @tadman

Comment: You could try `impl Default for Service` if that entire `impl Service` block is subject to specific constraints, assuming you can't tag specific functions as "not in scope" of that flag.

Comment: will try thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have multiple `impl` blocks for the same type, and that looks needed here since `new` wouldn't be a callable DBus method. Try structuring your code like so:

```
pub struct Service {
    start: Event,
    collections: Vec<Collection>,
    clients: Vec<Client>,
}

impl Service {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Service {
            start: event_listener::Event::new(),
            collections: Vec::new(),
            clients: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}

#[dbus_interface(name ="org.freedesktop.Secret.Service")]
impl Service {
    .....
}
```